# How to run Parameterized Tests with fixture member values in Google Test (gtest)?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, xunit

What I want to achieve is a Paramaterized Test `TEST_P(MyFixtureClass, DoStuff)`, with which I can test different values. Though said values shouldn't be constants, like those typically passed to `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P`. Moreover, I would want to use the values within some other fixture class - ideally.

There doesn't seem to be anything out there, which covers using fields instead of static values when creating parameterized tests. The [official documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#how-to-write-value-parameterized-tests) doesn't seem to cover this either - sadly.

---

But to avoid introducing the XY-problem in this question, here is the equivalent pseudo code:

The parameterized fixture, `MyFixture`:

```
struct MyFixture : OtherFixture, ::testing::WithParamInterface<float>
{
    float a;

    void SetUp() override
    {
        a = GetParam();
    }
};
```

`OtherFixture` would look like this:

```
struct OtherFixture : testing::Test
{
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;

    void SetUp() override
    {
        a = CalculateSomeFloat();
        b = CalculateSomeFloat();
        c = CalculateSomeFloat();
    }
};
```

The test case would be something like:

```
// This here is the key aspect.
// Basically, I do not want to write a bunch of tests for a, b and c.
// Rather, I'd just test all 3 with this one.
TEST_P(MyFixture, DoStuff)
{
    ...bunch of tests
}
```

And lastly, we would instantiate the parameterized tests:

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(MyFloatTesting, MyFixture, ::testing::Values(
    OtherFixture::a, OtherFixture::b, OtherFixture::c
));
```

Obviously, `OtherFixture::a` is inappropriate, but it illustrates where I would want to refer to a field, within a inherited fixture class (or any fixture class for that matter).

---

So is there any way to achieve this with gtest? I do not necessarily need to use parameterized tests. Simply avoiding having to write the same tests, for different objects is fine by me.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you need to use [`::testing::Combine`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#how-to-write-value-parameterized-tests).

And change the parameters from `float` to `std::tuple<float, float OtherFixture::*>`.

```
using OtherFixtureMemberAndValue = std::tuple<float, float OtherFixture::*>;

struct MyFixture : OtherFixture, ::testing::WithParamInterface<OtherFixtureMemberAndValue>
{
    float a = std::get<0>(GetParam());
    auto& memberToTest()
    {
        return this->*std::get<1>(GetParam());
    }


};
```

To define set of parameters use this approach:

```
const auto membersToTest = testing::Values(
     &OtherFixture::a, 
     &OtherFixture::b, 
     &OtherFixture::c
);

const auto floatValuesToTest = testing::Values(
    2.1, 
    3.2
    //  ... 
 );

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(AllMembers,
                        MyFixture,
                        testing::Combine(floatValuesToTest, membersToTest));
```

Then you can write your tests generic with respect to members of `OtherFixture`:

```
TEST_P(MyFixture, test)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(a, memberToTest());
}
```

I would also advice that you wrote [`PrintTo`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#teaching-google-test-how-to-print-your-values) for `float OtherFixture::*`:

```
void PrintTo(float OtherFixture::*member, std::ostream* os)
{
    if (member == &OtherFixture::a)
        *os << "&OtherFixture::a";
    else if (member == &OtherFixture::b)
        *os << "&OtherFixture::b";
    else if (member == &OtherFixture::c)
        *os << "&OtherFixture::c";
    else
        *os << "&OtherFixture::? = " << member;

}
```

In this way you get nice message in case of failure:

> [  FAILED  ] AllMembers/MyFixture.test/5, where GetParam() = (3.2,
>   &OtherFixture::c)

comparing to nasty, meaningless message w/o PrintTo:

> [  FAILED  ] AllMembers/MyFixture.test/5, where GetParam() = (3.2,
>   4-byte object <10-00 00-00>)

Comment: It didn't occur to me I could use function pointers, such as `float OtherFixture::*`. And I very much appreciate the `PrintTo` addition, thank you for going the extra mile.